# Is there a statute of limitations on crimes by nation states?

Tags: international-relations, international-law, international-courts

In the past, governments have sanctioned acts that are considered barbaric today. As far as I understand some of those nations are legal entities that still exist today. Are those nations legally culpable for the acts of previous governments? If so, how far back?

One example I thought of was the [Battle of Thermopylae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Thermopylae), 480 BCE. Nobody could seriously argue that any atrocities from that event are relevant 2500 years later. But the Spartan alliance and Achaemenid Persian Empire no longer exist as legal entities, so it's a moot point.

All other examples I can think of are unresolved and highly emotive. I am looking for any historical example where a sitting government was "found not guilty" due to the passage of time.

Comment: I think you should clarify what exactly you mean by "legally culpable". There are various ways such a question could be resolved. There are various international courts https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_court and each of them, in all likelihood, has separate rules on such matters. Other ways in which such questions may sometimes be resolved are treaties, most importantly peace treaties; and in those, there are likely no universal rules at all.

Comment: You should provide examples of things you think might be still relevant.

Comment: You are getting into international law which is primarily a question of treaties and charters and such. So it's either nation-to-nation or nation-in-relation-to-UN. These things don't really follow the kind of rules involved in the concept of statute of limitations.

Comment: @BobaFit There is also internal issues to consider and the people of the country could want to hold it accountable for actions in the past

Comment: @JoeW Oh, sure. That's going to depend on the details of the country involved and the nature of the crime. And exactly how it is deemed to be a crime "by the nation."

Comment: "All other examples I can think of are unresolved..." Really? The French Revolution is unresolved? The Napoleonic Wars are unresolved? The Crusades are unresolved? There is an awful lot of history that has happened really between 480 BC and today.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generally speaking, nation states cannot be charged with crimes.

When a country can be punished or required to make restitution for wrongdoing is strictly a question of political and diplomatic discretion that is not governed by the law or courts.

As a practical matter, it is effectively impossible to punish or seek restitution from a nation state which no longer exists.

Government officials who participated in criminal acts while acting in that capacity can be punished by courts criminally, but the particular acts and the particularly applicable laws in each case govern that question. Individual persons, however, can't be prosecuted after they are dead.

Comment: Specifying nation states (e.g. France) makes no sense here, it applies to all countries regardless of if they are nation states, empires, etc. Moreover, even when nation states exist continually (e.g. France), the country no longer exists (e.g. French monarchy pre-revolution and French Republic post revolution are different countries) and so the new country is not responsible for the actions, credits, debts, or obligations of the former entity unless they specifically mention that they are considered to be the same entity and will assume all obligations of the former (e.g. USSR -> Russia).

Comment: @uberhaxed The question asks about nation states, so I am replying to what was asked.

Comment: I'm fairly certain the title was a mistake and the author meant country, considering he gave 2 examples that are not nation states.

Comment: @uberhaxed Americans tend to use the term "nation states" to distinguish independent sovereign entities from US states.  It's not how "nation state" is defined in the dictionary, but it is nonetheless how many Americans interpret the term.  I don't know whether Lee McGee is American, but I know that ohwilleke is.  Just as the question continues to make sense if you substitute "country" for "nation state," so does this answer.  (...for certain senses of the word "country," that is.)

Comment: @phoog I'm not sure what Americans you are speaking to (I'm also American and we are not stupid); we use the word "country" when talking about countries.